# Django admin: search for foreign key objects rather than <select>?

Tags: django, django-admin

My model looks like this:

```
class Asset(models.Model):
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    asset_tag = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

class WorkOrder(models.Model):
    asset = models.ForeignKey(Asset)
```

Essentially, a work order is submitted and then an admin assigns an asset to the work order. The `asset_tag` field is a barcode that we can scan in.  When editing the work order in the Django admin, by default the `asset` field is displayed as a `<select>` widget.  What we want to be able to do is have a search field so that we can scan the asset tag and then search for the right asset in the DB to associate with the work order.

I know you can customize the Django admin foreign key to a hard coded query, but I can't figure out how to get it so it does a search based on a field on the admin page.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Did you take a look at [`raw_id_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields)?

It should be pretty to close to what you're after.

Answer (score 34):

If you are using **Django >= 2.0**, you can take advantage of a feature called [`autocomplete_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields). You must define `search_fields` on the related object’s ModelAdmin because the autocomplete search uses it.

Since you have a `ForeignKey` relationship to `Asset` in `WorkOrder`, in the `admin.py` of your app add the following:

```
from django.contrib import admin

@admin.register(Asset)
class AssetAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ["serial_number", "asset_tag"]


@admin.register(WorkOrder)
class WorkOrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    autocomplete_fields = ["asset"]
```

Add the fields you want to use for searching to `search_fields`, and add define `autocomplete_fields` as shown in the code above.

Answer (score 27):

Now you can use the [`autocomplete_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields) from django 2.0.

It's quite neat.